# How to output (using the write statement) an apostrophe " ' "?

Tags: linux, fortran, system, fortran90

I want to use system command in Fortran 90 for executing folowing command:

```
command =  awk '{print "C"NR,$1,$2,$3}' filename1 > filename2
call system(trim(command))
```

here my filename1 and filename2 are variables in a Fortran 90 program. 
But the problem is that any character can be assigned to a variable which are enclosed between apostrophes and my variable should also be consisting of apostrophes. I don't know how to type it in Fortran 90.

Answer (score 6):

Just use two apostrophes in a row inside the string

```
command =  'awk ''{print "C"NR,$1,$2,$3}'' filename1 > filename2'
```

Additionally, because I did not notice `filename1` and `filename2` are variables, you must append them as chw21 shows:

```
 // trim(filename1)//' > '//trim(filename2)
```

Comment: @MubeenaShaikh You don't have to thank, but you can consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use a parameter for single quotes, like this:

```
character, parameter :: sq = "'"
```

Then you can chain things together like this:

```
command = 'awk '//sq//'{print "C"NR,$1,$2,$3}'//sq//' '// &
           trim(filename1)//' > '//trim(filename2)
```

Or, you can swap between single- and double quoted strings:

```
command = "awk '" // '{print "C"NR,$1,$2,$3}' // "' " // &
           trim(filename1) // ' > ' // trim(filename2)
```

What you shouldn't do at all is using the Hollerith format instruction:

```
     write(command, 100) trim(f1), trim(f2)
100  FORMAT(29Hawk '{print "C"NR,$1,$2,$3}' , A, " > ", A)
```

That's why I'm not even telling you. Oh.

Comment: Seriously, don't use hollerith. It's been deleted as of Fortran 95 because it produces more problems than it solves.